# 'This title does not meet our quality standards'

Tags: discussion, error-message

Why does the following error come for me always?!

> This title does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that
>   it clearly summarizes your problem and uses proper grammar. You can
>   put details in the body of your question.

My title is:

> how to explode string lowercase delimiter

Comment: Try using capitalization (and proper grammer, as the message says). I'd try something like "**H**ow to explode string with **a** lowercase delimiter **?**". It's also easier to read for people looking for questions to answer.

Comment: If you are referring to your recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36841132/3933332 then your title isn't that bad. Grammar could be a bit better and as you already tagged your question with the keyword "case-insensitive" you could have used that for your title. (Also just to say: The duplicate wasn't worded very well so it might not be that easy to find it for someone who doesn't know it; So I rewrote the duplicate and your question; Also FYI: Duplicates aren't bad in the first place: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841 different wording can help for finding a problem/question better)